# Is this way of handling events in a Xamarin project memory safe?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I inherited a Xamarin project and I'm trying to find my way. The first task I completed involved creating a new reusable view and adding it to an existing screen. This was iOS specific, so I went and created a new .xib file to add in the relevant storyboard. I had some trouble figuring out how to attach the outlets correctly and I didn't see my view so I added it programmatically, but in the end I got it working. However I ended up using the following code that concerns me a bit:

```
    // TableviewSearchbarHeader.designer.cs
    [Register ("TableviewSearchbarHeader")]
    partial class TableviewSearchbarHeader
    {
        [Outlet]
        UIKit.UIButton ClearSelectionButton { get; set; }
    }

    // TableviewSearchbarHeader.cs
    public void SetOnClearSelectionButtonPressed(EventHandler OnClearSelectionButtonPressed)
    {
        ClearSelectionButton.TouchUpInside += OnClearSelectionButtonPressed;
    }

    // MyViewController.cs
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        TableviewSearchbarHeader.SetOnClearSelectionButtonPressed(OnClearSelectionButtonPressed);
    }
    private void OnClearSelectionButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.ResetFilter(this);
    }
```

The outlet is not accessible from the VC. So I had to create an entry point for the VC to assign its delegate implementation. But how can I be sure this will not cause a memory leak? This just seems like a code smell, but I couldn't figure out a better way and the docs aren't helpful.

What can I improve?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you tell us more about the purpose of the code? It's an entry point between what and the delegate?

Comment: @Mast The purpose is to have the OnClearSelectionButtonPressed method in the ViewController called when the user presses the button. This works by using the `+=` operator on the button's TouchUpInSide property and passing the method's name. However, in the ViewController where I have the method I want to assign, I don't have access to the button. So I created SetOnClearSelectionButtonPressed in TableviewSearchbarHeader.cs where I do have access to the button, and I call this method from my ViewController. So now I don't have to expose the button, and OnClearSelectionButtonPressed gets called.

Comment: @Mast My concern is that by doing it like this maybe I'm creating a memory leak somewhere. I'm unsure whether the button holds a reference to the ViewController's method and if that reference ever releases.